# How to host haskell app on amazon web services?

Tags: haskell, amazon-web-services

How can I host, say a Snap webapp, on amazon?
In other words, what are the first steps I need to take - as I am completely clueless.

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: I think this question might be too vague to be helpful to others. It sounds like you need to read some docs on AWS, read the docs on snap, and then see what specific questions you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to have an amazon aws account. Then depends on your requirements you can select the instances and host it. You can set up the instance using the AWS Management Console.
have a look on this. http://aws.amazon.com/console/
this will also help to you [Need a step by step guide to host a website on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620119/need-a-step-by-step-guide-to-host-a-website-on-aws)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I am kind of worried about security though. How can I ensure that I am securing everything correctly in Haskell etc...